# Why the variables are NULL?

Tags: objective-c

I got a problem to develop an app for iPhone.
I have to do a quiz.
The quiz is in a NSArray and each question has a title, some answers and a score by answers.
All these informations are in a NSMutableArray.

When I try to print the value "score" for exemple, I obtain a NULL and not the number.

Example:
  MYCOMMON.H

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"


@interface MyCommon : NSObject <FBRequestDelegate,FBDialogDelegate,FBSessionDelegate>
 {

    NSArray *quizz;
    int iCurrentQuestion;
    int iScore;
    int iRep;

    NSArray *permissions;

};

+ (MyCommon *)Singleton;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *quizz;
@property (assign) int iCurrentQuestion;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSArray *permissions;
@property (assign) int iScore;
@property (assign) int iRep;
@end


   MYCOMMON.M
@implementation MyCommon

static MyCommon * SingletonManager = nil;

@synthesize iCurrentQuestion, iScore, iRep;
@synthesize quizz;


-(id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

    iCurrentQuestion = 0;
        iRep = 0;
        iScore = 0;

        permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",nil] retain];

    }
    return self;

}

-(void)dealloc {

    // Do things
    [ super dealloc ];

}

- (int)GetScoreForReponse 
{    


    MyCommon *pCommon = [MyCommon Singleton];

    NSLog(@"GetScoreForReponse iScore : %@, pCommon.iScore);

    NSDictionary *dataItem = [quizz objectAtIndex:iCurrentQuestion];


    int add_score = 0;

    if (iRep == 1)
    {
            add_score = [[dataItem objectForKey:@"score1"]intValue];
    }
    else if (iRep == 2)
    {

         add_score =  [[dataItem objectForKey:@"score2"]intValue];
    }
    else if (iRep == 3)
    {
         add_score =  [[dataItem objectForKey:@"score3"]intValue];
    }
    else if (iRep == 4)
    {
         add_score =  [[dataItem objectForKey:@"score4"]intValue];
    }
    else if (iRep == 5)
    {
         add_score =  [[dataItem objectForKey:@"score5"]intValue];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"error !");

    return add_score;
}
```

Thank for help !

Comment: Does that compile? This line seems malformed to me `NSLog(@"GetScoreForReponse iScore : %@, pCommon.iScore);`

Comment: On a side note, is that code leaking memory with a double retain on the permissions NSArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to print the description of an Objective-C object referenced by the address stored in iScore by using %@, use %d instead. If iScore was non zero that would more than likely result in a crash rather than NULL.

```
NSLog(@"GetScoreForReponse iScore : %d", pCommon.iScore);
```

Here is a list of [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).